# can elasticsearch periodically aggregate data and save it as other index data?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

now i save a website login detail every day.

use index like `login-20211201`.

i want remove old data by `curator`, but i need save all login aggregate data, like

```
20201201 
success: 123
fail: 4444
....
```

and use elasticsearch analyse the data, how to realize?

I came up with a way like this
use `crontab` request elasticsearch api every day and use the result to put new document to elasticsearch, is there other better way to solve? can i aggregation data directly in elasticsearch?

think you! my English is poor.

Comment: You can use [transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the above comment by [leandrojmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123206/leandrojmp), take a look at rollups and transforms - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/data-rollup-transform.html

Comment: ok, think you, i will try